# Using eval() to execute string of PHP that contains SimpleHTML

Tags: php, html, dom, eval, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to use eval() to execute a string of SimpleHTML. I'm fully aware of the dangers of eval() and will not be using any user input for the string that is to be executed.

```
$my_data = str_get_html('<html><body><a href=\"https://www.example.com\">Hello!</a></body></html>');

$str = '$my_data->find(\'a\', 0)->attr[\'href\']';

eval ("\$str = \"$str\";");

echo $str;
```

The above code doesn't execute, and after echoing $str, I get:

```
('a', 0)->attr['href']
```

What happened to the first part of the $str string (i.e. **$my_data->find** )? How can I actually execute the code from the $str string?

Comment: Why do you think you have to use the **evil** `eval()` at all?

Comment: Maybe I don't, but I'm not sure what other options I have. Each of my 'selectors' that will be within the $str string will be completely different in format. Some will have parameters for the find method, some won't. Some will be using CSS selectors while others will use more SimpleHTML DOM syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are passing to the eval is wrong. You are trying to eval the following code:

```
$str = "$my_data->find('a', 0)->attr['href']";
```

The correct code would be:

```
$str = $my_data->find('a', 0)->attr['href'];
```

Or:

```
$str = "{$my_data->find('a', 0)->attr['href']}";
```

This code works:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/simplehtmldom_1_9_1/simple_html_dom.php';

$my_data = str_get_html('<html><body><a href=\"https://www.example.com\">Hello!</a></body></html>');

$str = '$my_data->find(\'a\', 0)->attr[\'href\']';


eval ("\$str = $str;");

echo $str;
```